# javascript: how to work with libs that suppress exceptions in callbacks?

Tags: javascript

lots of javascript libs and frameworks accepts functions that are called after some operation is completed. For example:

```
chrome.storage.local.get( 'foo', function() { console.log( "foo" ); } );
```

But i just realized that some API's, including google local storage api mentioned above catch and suppress all exceptions in functions being called. For example, if i modify a code above to have an error (`ReferenceError` that i want to see in console):

```
chrome.storage.local.get( 'foo', function() { a.b(); } );
```

No error will be raised since api suppress it by catching and ignoring all errors. How to debug my code in such situations? Is it any way to bring errors back or all this api's are just not intended to be used with complex code and i need to debug via `console.log` manually to find what have failed?

**UPDATE 1**

Simply adding my own try-catch to all callback will add complexity to code that is not really welcome. Also, simple `console.log` is worse than exception since exception is catched by dev tools, displayed in red, have stack trace attached etc. Of course all this can be emulated with `console.log` but this will add more complexity.

**UPDATE 2**

Seems it's a ommon practice for js code to ignore errors, so i was forced to implement ugly solution by adding underscore plugin and using it to envelope each callback:

```
function _safeblock( block )
{
  console.assert( block );
  return function() {
    try {
      block.apply( this, arguments );
    }
    catch( e ) {
      console.log( e.message, e.stack );
    }
  };
}


function _safecall( block )
{
  console.assert( block );
  _safeblock( block )();
}


_.mixin({
  safeblock: _safeblock,
  safecall: _safecall,
});
```

Comment: what did you end up doing to solve this issue?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I implemented an ugly solution by enveloping each third-party callback into safety code. But it's just a temporal hack, not a proper architectural solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try catch them yourself.

```
chrome.storage.local.get( 'foo', function() {
    try{
        a.b();
    }catch(e){
        console.log(e);
        //do whatever
    } 
});
```

You can automate this, either by overriding `storage.local.get` or by creating a generic function wrapper.

You can also defer the function manually with setTimeout which would make it impossible (in the browser) for the library to suppress your errors

```
chrome.storage.local.get( 'foo', function() {
     setTimeout(function(){
           a.b();
     });
});
```

This would not give you very meaningful stack traces though (anything outside the function will not show) which makes it less useful. It's also likely a performance overhead if you use this in performance sensitive situations (and in browsers setTimeout takes at least a few miliseconds, there is a postMessage hack around it though).

Comment: Protecting ALL callbacks in ALL API calls will add code complexity.

Comment: You are right, and it will. You _will_ have to either proxy all API methods or try/catch all API calls. Write a wrapper for the API. Suppressing all exceptions is a bad design call in an API IMO, especially if you're not giving something like "debug mode". This is true for languages other than JS too.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply perform a try-catch and use `console.error` (works in Firebug and Chrome DevTools, not sure about others):

```
chrome.storage.local.get('foo', function () 
{   try { a.b(); }
    catch (e) { console.error(e.name + ": " + e.message); }
});
```

If you didn't need arguments for your callback, you could create a wrapper function:

```
function wrapTryCatch(func)
{   return function ()
    {   try { func.apply(this, arguments); }
        catch (e)
        {   var err = e.name + ': ' + e.message;
            console.error ? console.error(err)
            : console.log ? console.log(err)
            : alert(err);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Protecting ALL callbacks in ALL API calls will add code complexity.

Comment: @EyeofHell: it's unlikely that it's not a necessary evil, but I'll do some more research.

Comment: I'm not saying it's evil and i will use this approach unless i find something better. But i don't like to add complexity to my code without any clear reason. Maybe this problem is well-known and it's something like hidden switch in google chrome or global java setting that changes things back to normal.

Comment: @EyeofHell the problem _is_ known and the solution around it is to not write APIs that do this. In node you could have used domains to address the issue.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum It's strange that `google` use such bad practice :(.